# Splitting the values in column using regex

Tags: regex, r, split, gsub

I have data.frame with two columns like the following

```
dat

    ID                             Details                         
    id_1        box1_homodomain gn=box1 os=homo sapiens p=4 se=1   
    id_2        sox2_plurinet gn=plu os=mus musculus p=5 se=3
```

I would like to split the "os=xxx" and gn="yyy" in column "Details" for all the ids and print it like following:

```
    Id   Description        gn      os               
   Îd_1  box1_homodomain    box1    homo sapiens   
   Id_2  sox2_plurinet      plu     mouse musculus
```

I tried the using gsub approach in R but I am unable to split the os=homo sapiens and gn=box1 into their respective columns. The following R code I used

```
dat$gn=gsub('^[gn=][A-z][A-z]`,dat$Details)
dat$os=gsub('^[os=][A-z][A-z]`,dat$Details)
```

Can anyone tell me what wrong and how can it be corrected. Kindly help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your regex seems to work fine

Comment: The gsub syntax is invalid because it's mixing normal `'` with backticks and because gsub takes 3 arguments and the second is missing here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an option with tidyr:

```
library(tidyr)
# specify the new column names:
vars <- c("Description", "gn", "os")
# then separate the "Details" column according to regex and drop extra columns:
separate(dat, Details, into = vars, sep = "[A-Za-z]+=", extra = "drop")
#    ID      Description    gn            os
#1 id_1 box1_homodomain  box1  homo sapiens 
#2 id_2   sox2_plurinet   plu  mus musculus
```

Comment: @Thileepan, I don't understand your comment. Can you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: Thanks @docendo discimus. It worked fine. Also I have another column,GOs. In that column there values like P:pos_1;P:pos_2;F:Fun_1;F:F_2;C:Com_1;C:Com. I would like split thi column also into P(which should consists of all entries starting with P:xxx; );F(which should consists of all entries starting with F: and ending with; );C(which should consists of all entries starting with C:xxx; ). I  tried like "separate(seq, GOs, into = c("P", "F", "C"), sep = "[a-z]+=")" but it throwed me error

Comment: That's a different case. You should better include that in the question with sample data and expected output so everyone can see it. You would need to adjust the regex where to split the data.

Comment: SO can I edit the same question or should ask that question separately.?

Comment: You can make an edit at the bottom of your current question and add the example for the other column if it's not a completely different situation

Comment: docendo discimus I have edited my question. Please take look and guide me.

Comment: @Thileepan, the "GO" column would actually require a different approach then the previous column. It's more complicated because there's not a simple pattern you can use to split the column by. Therefore I suggest you ask it in a separate question and make a "rollback" of this question to the original version (I can do that for you).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70955/discussion-between-thileepan-and-docendo-discimus).

Answer (score 5):

**1) sub and gsub** To do it using `sub` and `gsub` as in the question try this.  Note that each regular expressions should match all of `dat$Details` so that when we replace it with the capture group only the capture group remains.  For the `dat$GO` as in the comments to the question, we remove everything up to but not including `P:`, replace all occurrences of `;P` with a comma and remove `P:` and also remove semicolon and everything thereafter.  Similarly for `F` and `C`:

```
data.frame(dat[1], 
   Description = sub(" .*", "", dat$Details),
   gn = sub(".*gn=(.*) os=.*", "\\1", dat$Details),
   os = sub(".*os=(.*) p=.*", "\\1", dat$Details),
   P = gsub("P:|;.*", "", gsub(";P:", ",", sub(".*?P:", "P:", dat$GO))),
   F = gsub("F:|;.*", "", gsub(";F:", ",", sub(".*?F:", "F:", dat$GO))),
   C = gsub("C:|;.*", "", gsub(";C:", ",", sub(".*?C:", "C:", dat$GO))))
```

giving:

```
    ID     Description   gn           os       P       F       C
1 id_1 box1_homodomain box1 homo sapiens p_1,p_2     F_1 C_1,C_2
2 id_2   sox2_plurinet  plu mus musculus     p_1 F_1,F_2     C_1
```

**2) read.pattern**  Processing of `dat$Details` is a bit easier with `read.pattern` [(link)](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/gsubfn/man/read.pattern.html) in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) as one can define a *single* regular expression  whose capture groups represent the fields of interest.  Processing of `dat$GO` can be simplified too by extracting the `P:...` fields using `strapplyc` [(link)](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/gsubfn/docs/strapply) and then concatenating them together with `paste` (and similarly with the `F` and `C` fields):

```
library(gsubfn)

Sub <- function(string, pat) sapply(strapplyc(string, pat), paste, collapse = ",")

DF <- read.pattern(text = as.character(dat$Details), 
        pattern = "(.*) gn=(.*) os=(.*) p=",
        col.names = c("Description", "gn", "os"),
        as.is = TRUE)

cbind(dat[1], DF,
      P = Sub(dat$GO, "P:(.*?);"),
      F = Sub(dat$GO, "F:(.*?);"),
      C = Sub(dat$GO, "C:(.*?);"))
```

giving:

```
    ID     Description   gn           os       P       F       C
1 id_1 box1_homodomain box1 homo sapiens p_1,p_2     F_1 C_1,C_2
2 id_2   sox2_plurinet  plu mus musculus     p_1 F_1,F_2     C_1
```

Here is a visualization of the regular expression used in `read.pattern`:

```
(.*) gn=(.*) os=(.*) p=
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/DAY9U1oIP2ixLUuy)

**Notes**

1) If the `dat$Details` column is already character we could omit `as.character`.  We could also omit `as.is=TRUE` if its ok to have `factor` columns in the result.

2) the sample output in the question has `mouse` but the input has `mus`.  We have assumed it should be `mus` in both cases.

3) We used this for `dat`:

```
dat <-
structure(list(ID = c("id_1", "id_2"), 
Details = c("box1_homodomain gn=box1 os=homo sapiens p=4 se=1", 
"sox2_plurinet gn=plu os=mus musculus p=5 se=3"), 
GO = c("P:p_1;P:p_2;F:F_1;C:C_1;C:C_2;  ", 
"P:p_1;F:F_1;F:F_2;C:C_1;")), .Names = c("ID", "Details", 
"GO"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

In the future please post the result of `dput(dat)` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of regex capture groups for that.
Each capture group match may be extracted with e.g. the `stri_match_first_regex` function from the `stringi` package.

```
dat <- data.frame(
   ID=c("id_1", "id_2"),
   details=c("box1_homodomain gn=box1 os=homo sapiens p=4 se=1", "sox2_plurinet gn=plu os=mus musculus p=5 se=3")
)

library(stringi)
res <- stri_match_first_regex(dat$details, "^(.+) gn=(.+) os=(.+) p=.*$")
res[,1] <- dat$ID
res <- as.data.frame(res)
names(res) <- c("ID", "Description", "gn", "os")
res
##   ID     Description   gn           os
## 1  1 box1_homodomain box1 homo sapiens
## 2  2   sox2_plurinet  plu mus musculus
```