# In R: tidyr split and swing value into column name using regex

Tags: regex, r, tidyr

Im trying to get customized with the `tidyr`package, and am strugling with the problem of having a variable which is a concatenate of several variables. In the minimal example below, I would like to split variable `v2` into its constituent variables `v3`and `v4`and then swing these so I end up with the four variables `v1`-`v4`.

```
require(plyr)
require(dplyr)
require(stringr)
require(tidyr)    
data <- 
      data.frame(
        v1=c(1,2),
        v2=c("v3 cheese; v4 200", "v3 ham; v4 150")) %>%
      tbl_df()
```

If I split `v2` into a new `temp` I get only `v3`:

```
mutate(data, 
      temp=unlist(sapply(str_split(data$v2, pattern=";"), "[", 1)))

  v1                v2      temp
1  1 v3 cheese; v4 200 v3 cheese
2  2    v3 ham; v4 150    v3 ham
```

My problems are:

- 1) How do I split and swing `v3` AND `v4` up as column names using `tidyr`?
- 2)    In my real data I do not know (or they are to many) the
  variable    names but they have the structure "var value", and I
  would like to use some regex to automatically identify and swing
  them as in 1)

Got inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525431/splitting-the-values-in-column-using-regex)  SO answer but could not get it to work though with regex code for variable names.

UPDATE:
My output would be something like (`v2` could be skipped as its now redundant with `v3` and `v4`):

```
    v1  v2  v3  v4
1   1   v3 cheese; v4 200   cheese  200
2   2   v3 ham; v4 150  ham 150
```

Comment: Can you show your desired output?

Comment: @David Arenburg: Sure, see UPDATE above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the data by ";", convert the split output to a long form, split the data again by " " (but in a wide form this time) and spread the values out to the wide form you desire.

Here it is using "dplyr" + "tidyr" + "stringi":

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringi)

data %>%
  mutate(v2 = stri_split_fixed(as.character(v2), ";")) %>%
  unnest(v2) %>%
  mutate(v2 = stri_trim_both(v2)) %>%
  separate(v2, into = c("var", "val")) %>%
  spread(var, val)
# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# 
#   v1     v3  v4
# 1  1 cheese 200
# 2  2    ham 150
```

Alternatively, using `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package (which doesn't presently work with `tbl_df`s)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(splitstackshape)

as.data.frame(data) %>%
  cSplit("v2", ";", "long") %>%
  cSplit("v2", " ") %>%
  spread(v2_1, v2_2) 
#    v1     v3  v4
# 1:  1 cheese 200
# 2:  2    ham 150
```

Comment: Nice, I didnt know of package stringi. Whats the format you get for `v2` after `stri_split_fixed` ?

Comment: @user3375672, `stri_split_fixed` would give you a `list`, which we convert to a long form by using `unnest` from "tidyr".

Comment: It works fine on the play data, but in my "real" data I get  "Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (.....)" after `spread()`. It seems like the error is given for some rows where `var` is the same (but other columns are different, and hence ´unique()´ does not solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3375672, Which approach are you using? The first or second? It sounds like you would need to create a unique ID before the first split. That is, I'm guessing that your source data itself has duplicated "v1" values.

Comment: Of cause! Solved by mutate(id=rownames(.)). Perfect!